# Something like VMware "Changed Block Tracking" (CBT) in linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, storage

I'm wondering if is there any possibility to track changed blocks in linux with an ext3/ext4 filesystem (or a specific one supporting it).
I mean a feture like the *Changed Block Tracking* (CBT) available on ESX/ESXi systems. I refers to the feature discussed here:

[What is Changed Block Tracking (CBT)](http://searchvmware.techtarget.com/definition/Changed-Block-Tracking-CBT)
[Understanding Changed Block Tracking on Virtual Machines](http://techlib.barracuda.com/display/BBSV42/Understanding+Changed+Block+Tracking+on+Virtual+Machines).

Comment: qcow2 provides this - https://lwn.net/Articles/837053/

Comment: Thank you @symcbean, that's interesting.

Answer (score 1):

BTRFS, and ZFS provide mechanisms to backup "changed blocks" between snapshots.

Meaning you would take an initial FULL snapshot + backup of your volume.  Then later you can create a second snapshot, and export the differences between the two; which are effectively the changed blocks only.

There are also changed-block solutions on the Ceph/Rados Clustered Storage solution.  Where the RBD block devices can also be snapshotted, and diff'd.

Comment: Hello Ron, for what is my understanding, following the approach you're suggesting, one should still compare two situations and build and identify the changed block (or file subset). For this reason, I don't see any advantage like comparing directly to files and find the differences (like rsync does). But maybe I misunderstood your solution.

Answer (score 1):

BTRFS and ZFS can caluclate a difference between two snapshot, then you can backup only the difference via tools like btrfs-send. But the oldest snapshot must exists on your disk. You can't delete it.
This adds some complexity and constraints to your snapshot management, and increases disk space usage a lot. For example if you want to have two different backup destinations and schedules, you must not delete two old snapshots and keep them as a reference, wasting a huge amount of disk space.

With VMWare CBT life is esasier: the backup system can calulate the changed block difference from a non exixting (deleted) snapshot to your current snapshot. There is no need to waste space keeping older snapshot on the disk.

A feature like CBT in BTRFS/ZFS will be very appreciated to incrementally backup a BTRFS or ZFS filesystem.